# Specific URL Blocked

Tags: connection-issues, htc-one-m8, nexus-9

I have a Nexus 9 and a HTC One M8.

On both Devices my Access to a specific URL is somehow "blocked" through browser and  through App.

With blocked i mean the following behavior:

- Website (or the App) is able to load some text Data. This process takes quite some time.
- Pictures and Video wont load at all.
- There is never a "Connection Problem" Error
- If i connect to the URL over Mobile Data everything works.

Things i tried:

- Access URL over PC (works)
- Reboot Device / Reinstall App
- Reboot the Modem
- Deleted the Cookies  / Cache in Chrome
- WiFi Turned off and on / Delete the WiFi and added it new
- Ping the URL form the android Device (0 Packages lost; 45ms avg)

As far as i can tell the Problem occurs between the communication from my Devices to the Modem.

The URL is www.viki.com

But i have really no clue what i could do next (besides Factory Reset, wich i would like to avoid)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There may be packet loss occurring on your network. Try pinging the site.

Windows:  ping www.viki.com(Windows will auto 6 pings)
Linux:    ping -c(x) www.viki.com(where x is the number of times to ping)

If the result is that there is substantial packet loss(above 10%) try clearing your DNS Cache.

Windows: type cmd within Windows search to get Command Terminal then type:ipconfig/flushdns at the C:>
Linux: Depends on the Linux distro.  usually located in /etc/init.d  Once in the /etc/init.d directory see if there is a file named "dns-clean"  if there is just type:  ./dns-clean  then try to log on to www.viki.com again.  Hope this helps but keep in mind that there could be other causes for your problem but this is a good start.  Good Luck!

Comment: I Pinged the URL with my Android 100 Times: 0 Packages Lost, avg Ping Time 44 ms. Does not seem to be the Problem :/

Comment: Try going into the Wi-Fi Networks menu option on your devices and "forget" or delete any access points that you haven't used recently. Most of the time when I have issues connecting to websites that is the cause.